# ¿por que mi script entra en un loop al cargar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, html5

La función de mi script es enviar un formulario al cargar la pagina, pero entra en un bucle infinito, alguien con mas experiencia que me pueda ayudar, yo apenas estoy aprendiendo y no entiendo muy bien por que pasa.

este es mi controlador, el servlet que recibe la acción y devuelve el formulario:

```
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String accion=request.getParameter("accion");
    productos=pdao.listar();
    System.out.println ("los productos son:" + productos);

    switch (accion){
            case "Listar":
            request.setAttribute("lista",productos);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("catalogo.jsp").forward(request,response);
            break;
            default:
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?accion=Listar").forward(request,response);
            break;
        }
}
```

y el  catalogo.jsp donde cargo el formulario nuevamente y se produce el bucle, no coloco mucho codigo por que StackOverflow me pide mas detalles que código:

```
   <main role="main">

   <section class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <h1>Productos</h1>
      <p class="lead text-muted">Ponemos a tu disposicion nuestros productos, visitanos en nuestra tienda y será un gusto atenderte.</p>
      <!-- <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Main call to action</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Secondary action</a>
      </p> -->
     <p>
      <form name="miformulario" action="Controlador" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="Listar">
        <!--   <input type="file" name="fileFoto"> -->
      </form>
      </p>
    </div>
  </section> 

  
<div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row">
     <c:forEach var="p" items="${lista}"> 
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
              <label>${p.getNombre()}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <i>${p.getPrecio_venta()}</i>
            <img src="ControladorIMG?id=${p.getId()}" width="200" height="180">
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-center"> 
            <label>${p.getDescripcion()}</label>
            <!-- <div>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-info">Agregar a Carrito</a>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Comprar</a>
            </div> -->
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </div>
     </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>

</main>
```

Comment: ¿El formulario se carga en la misma página?

Comment: si, ese es el problema? supongo que al terminar de cargar se llama otra vez la función? como lo puedo corregir?

Comment: Lo primero es saber porqué quieres enviar el formulario en cuanto se carga la página, quizá deberías hacerlo por petición _AJAX_, pero necesitas proporcionar más información.

Comment: quiero que liste información de la base de datos  automáticamente al cargar la pagina

Comment: Pues básicamente, cuando se termina de cargar tu página se envía tu formulario al controlador, como estás llamando al evento submit(), cuando se haya enviado el formulario este hará que se refresque la página y aquí volvemos al principio.

Comment: Entonces, elimina ese _javascript_ y ejecuta el código normalmente, inicializando la variable `accion` y las correspondientes a otros campos con valores por defecto. Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para procesar el formulario y poder sugerirte una solución.

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la que ves un ciclo infinito es que estás enviando el formulario, pero no por ajax sino haciendo un envío del form... se envía la data y se vuelve a cargar la página entonces vuelves a enviar el form y se vuelve a cargar la página y así sucesivamente. Si necesitas enviar ese formulario (suena a redundante, pero en fin.... de pronto estás usando algún truco) entonces deberías enviarlo por ajax para que no se vuelva a cargar la página.

Comment: ok ya entendí, es redundante enviar el form,  no estoy accediendo adecuadamente,creo que lo tengo que hacer desde el href, pero no tengo mucha experiencia en esto, gracias por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Elimina el envío de formulario por *Javascript* y asegúrate de tener un valor adecuado para `accion`:

```
String accion=request.getParameter("accion");
if(accion == null) {
    accion = "Listar";
}
```

Otra opción es eliminar "Listar" y dejar que esa opción se ejecute por defecto en el `switch`:

```
switch (accion) {
    case "Primera":
        // Ejecutar acciones correspondientes y terminar
        break;
    case "Otra":
        // Ejecutar acciones correspondientes y terminar
        break;
    // No es necesario case "Listar", porque se ejecutará en "default"
    // Cuando no cumpla con las condiciones anteriores
    // case "Listar":
    default:
        request.setAttribute("lista",productos);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("catalogo.jsp").forward(request,response);
        break;
}
```